# Horizontal alignment in flalign

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I feel like this will probably be an obvious one, but I've been struggling to keep the horizontal spacing tight in flalign; but with:

```
\begin{flalign*}        
&\int_{-\pi}^{0} f(x)dx                                     &&  <  0     & \\        
&- \Big( \int_{-\pi}^{0} \underbrace{f(x)}_{\leq 0}dx \Big) &&  = -(-2)  & \\        
&                                                           &&  = 2      &                      
\end{flalign*}
```

I'm getting huge blanks between the two members of the expressions. I've tried all kinds of ampersand arrangements, but no luck so far. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `flalign` is "full length" align so designed to be rather wide, also you have blank cells at the start of each line and before each operator . There is only one alignment point here so should only be one `&` (with `align`)  but you have four per line.

Comment: If you're using `flalign` for “flush left align”, don't; that's the job of the `fleqn` option instead (and possibly of `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}`).

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to align on the left margin  for a particular alignment with flalign*, you can insert an `alignedat` environment. I took the liberty to replace `\underbrace` with `\underbracket` (from `mathtools`), which looks nicer, in my opinion, for short items:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}


\begin{flalign*}
    &\! \begin{alignedat}{2} & \int_{-\pi}^{0} f(x)dx& & < 0 \\
    &- \Big( \int_{-\pi}^{0} \underbracket[0.4pt][0.5ex]{f(x)}_{\leq 0}dx \Big) && = -(-2) \\
    & && = 2
    \end{alignedat} &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, great! Agreed, the underbracket does indeed look nicer. Thanks a bunch.